# Mobile Menu Toggle to Text

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I currently am running a WordPress site (using Avada theme) https://busybins.co.uk - currently as is with most WordPress sites when the site is viewed on a mobile it has the 3 toggle lines.

My question is this - can I change the 3 toggle lines to say MENU, if yes how?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
.fusion-icon-bars:before {
    content: "\f0c9";
}
```

to

```
.fusion-icon-bars:before {
     content: "MENU";
}
```

This icon is being determined by the property `content` which you should be able to either override or just go in the code and change it yourself.

Comment: Hi Sorry that has not worked - I have a) added the code to custom CSS and b) edited it in the editor - I noticed the editor noted the item you was on about as .fusionicon-bars:before. but despite editing this with the same options as you provided didn't edit the menu.

Comment: @AndyReachDigital don't normally recommend it but for the sake of seeing if there's another issue did you try using an !important tag. I also noticed in your comment you put .fusionicon and not .fusion-icon.